# How to draw downwards using turtle Lib

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    print(x, y)


turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-120, 15)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.goto(-120,25)


turtle.backward(30)
turtle.right(30)

mainloop()
```

This is my code here and I am trying to draw downwards and make a triangle sort of shape

[image]

I was expecting the turtle.backwards(30) to go down. I tried searching for the method to do so but I could not find any so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What result do you get when you try the code, and how is that different from what you want? Next, what exactly is your reasoning? For example, where the code says `turtle.goto(-120, 15)`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? Where on the screen do you expect that point to be? When the code then says `turtle.goto(-120,25)`, where do you expect that to be? What direction do you expect the turtle to face after that step, and why? "I was expecting the turtle.backwards(30) to go down" again, why?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding I realized you had to change the angle to be able to go in the direction you are wanting to go towards. I thought there would be a function that goes downwards like frontwards but I have cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to draw in turtle: absolutely or relatively.

`goto`, `setpos` and so forth are absolute actions. Regardless of where the turtle is heading and currently located, the turtle goes directly to the new point without changing its heading. The only relativistic aspect of these commands is that the line the turtle might draw depends on its last location.

`forward` and `backward` are relative movements. They depend on where the turtle is located and where it's heading (facing) at the time of the call. The turtle starts out located at 0, 0 and heading towards the right side of the screen from your perspective, pointing at 0 degrees.

In your code, when you use `turtle.backward(30)`, your turtle facing right from your perspective takes 30 steps towards the left side of the screen, starting from the position at the last `goto`.

If you want `backward` and `forward` to go in some other axis than along the flat left-right line in the middle of the screen (from your perspective), you can use `setheading`, `towards`, `left` or `right` to change the turtle's heading.

As with positioning commands, heading commands are either relative or absolute. `left` and `right` are relative heading changes, meaning they take the current heading into account, while `setheading` is absolute, setting the heading to the parameter value regardless of the current turtle's heading.

If this is still unclear, you can think of it as the difference between assignment/set/`=` and change/increment/decrement/`+=`/`-=` operations. When you say `x = 42`, the previous value of `x` is ignored, so it's absolute. On the other hand, `x += 42` depends on its previous value, so it's relative.

As far as drawing your partial triangle shape, you can do it with absolute movements or with relative movements.

Here's how to draw that shape with absolute movements:

```py
import turtle

turtle.goto(0, 80)
turtle.goto(40, 0)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

With relative movements:

```py
import turtle

turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(80)
turtle.right(160)
turtle.forward(87)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

You can see a problem with the relative movements: it's unclear how far to move to get to 0. There are ways to deal with this (trigonometry, for example), but I'll leave things as is here to stay in scope.

Relative movements are usually best when you plan to rotate the whole shape.

As a general rule of thumb, try to avoid excessive use of `backward`, except if it saves a fair amount of rotation or makes the most sense in context. It strikes me as a bit harder to reason about than `forward`.

---

As an aside, always avoid `from turtle import *`. This dumps over 150 methods into the global namespace, leading to confusion about when you're dealing with the pre-instantiated turtle. It's easy to overwrite core turtle functions with your own functions. Bugs and wasted time tend to ensue.

Creating an instance helps avoid confusion, `t = turtle.Turtle()` or even `import Screen, Turtle` and never using `turtle`. This forces you to create an instance.

Comment: I feel like we ought to have a canonical for this, although I'm not sure exactly what question naturally summons all this information (or if it would be properly focused).